# Create index without specifying the tablespace

Tags: oracle, indexing, oracle11g, tablespace

I'd like to ask a question.
What happen If I create an index without specifying the tablespace in the process of creation.
For example :

```
CREATE INDEX indx_cd on distributors(dist_cd)
```

In what tablespace does the index created?  And will the index still works as it should even if I put it that way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The index will be created in the default tablespace of the schema.

As system user you can determine what tablespace that is:

```
select username,default_tablespace from dba_users
```

Comment: Thank You.  Even if the index was created in default tablespace, the index will still working as it should right?

Comment: Yes, there's nothing wrong with the default tablespace. Its a tablespace like any other. It's just a matter of how you want to organize things in your database (where goes what).

Comment: @RedFux227 - A tablespace is a logical allocation of space which makes it easier to administer a database.  In reality it might be striped across several physical drives which themselves are likely to be RAIDs.  So it won't affect performance if you have indexes and tables on the same tablespace.

Comment: Rene & @APC - So the point is it doesn't matter which tablespace the index was on (even if the index's tablespace with the related indexed column is on different tablespace), the index will be still indexing the related column.  Right?